# passing label value to views.py django

Tags: python, django

Before i asked this question, I have searched online and found similar solutions. However, it does not work for my case.

I would like to pass template value to views.py. I tried using request.POST.get('value') but it does not work. I would like the name of the selected student to be saved in the database when the submit button is clicked.

i received an error: Cannot assign "''": "MarkAtt.studName" must be a "Namelist" instance.

Here is my UI:

[image]

Here are my codes:

Views.py

```
 def AbsentStudent(request, id=None):
    classGrp = None
    attendance= 0
    today = datetime.datetime.now()
    group = GroupInfo.objects.get(id=id)
    q1 = Namelist.objects.filter(classGrp=id).values('name','id') #get the student name of the specific group
    q2 = MarkAtt.objects.all().values('studName__name','id')   #get the name of attended students fr the lab
    q3 = q1.difference(q2) #to get the absentee names: name and id only 

    form_class = studStatus
    form = form_class(request.POST)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            a = form.save(commit=False)
            a.currentDate = datetime.datetime.now().date()
            a.classGrp = group
            a.attendance = attendance
            a.studName = request.POST.get('studID','') //error...


            #getId = request.POST.get('id')
            #tried.studName = getId.get(id=getId)
            form.save()
            return redirect('editStudStatus',id)
        else:
            form = studStatus(request.POST )



    context = { 
    'q3' :  q3,
    'group' : group,
    'form' : form,
    'today' :today,
    # 'q5' : q5



    }

    return render(request,'studDetails.html',context, {'form':form})
```

Template:

```
   <tbody>
          {% for q in q3 %}
            <tr>


                <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
<td>{{q.name}}</td> 
                <td><input type="label" value={{q.id}} name="studID"/></td></td>
                <td>{{form.status }}</td>
                <td>{{form.remarks}}</td>


                <td><button type ="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success" >Submit</button>
                </form></td>

            </tr>   

        {% endfor %}

    </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to use multiple form without defferent actions.You can pass your ids to action like this:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url "url name" id=q.id %}">
```

Comment: i received this error: Reverse for 'editStudStatus' with arguments '('AGGARWAL ANOUSHKA',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['show/student/(?P<id>\\d+)/$'].